# Pause Angular Animations

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular5, angular-animations

Is it possible to pause animations in Angular 2+? I would like to pause an animation upon mousing over an element and resume the animation from where it left off when mousing out.

I have created a simple script to demonstrate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/scrolling-text

Here's my component:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="scrolling-text" [@scroll]="state" (@scroll.done)="scrollDone()">Hover to pause!</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .container {
      height: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .scrolling-text {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /* Below doesn't work to pause */

    .scrolling-text:hover, .container:hover {
      -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }
  `],
  animations: [
    trigger('scroll', [
      state('on', style({left: '-100px'})),
      transition('* => *', [
        style({left: '-100px'}),
        animate(10000, style({left: '100%'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  state = 0;

  scrollDone() {
    this.state++;
  }

}
```

I tried `animation-play-state: paused;` without luck:

```css
.scrolling-text:hover, .container:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it with `AnimationBuilder`.

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { style, animate, AnimationBuilder, AnimationPlayer } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div class="container" (mouseover)="player.pause()" (mouseout)="player.play()">
    <div #el class="scrolling-text">Hover to pause!</div>
  </div>
`,
styles: [`
  .container {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .scrolling-text {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
`]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef;

  private factory = this.builder.build([
    style({left: '-100px'}),
    animate(10000, style({left: '100%'}))
  ]);
  private player;

  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.player = this.factory.create(this.el.nativeElement, {});
    this.animate();
  }

  private animate() {
    this.player.reset();

    this.player.onDone(() => {
      this.animate();
    });

    this.player.play();
  }

}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scrolling-text-ja3aju)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution though.
Since

```
this.player = this.factory.create(this.el.nativeElement, {});
```

creates another instance of WebAnimationsPlayer inside RendererAnimationPlayer

You can check it yourself by:

```
 console.log(this.player._renderer.engine.players.length);
```

Of course in your case it is not critical but still.
This comes into play when you try to reuse animation in something like mousemove event. Then Angular can create up to 1000 players. And overflow the memory.

If you want to reuse animation more memory efficient you should reuse the existing player.

Or call

```
 if (this.player) {
      this.player.destroy();
 }
```

before

```
this.player = this.factory.create(this.el.nativeElement, {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sergey. It is good info. I actually had already modified my demo to reuse the player, but it looks like I never updated my answer. I have done that now.